# transforming sequence of STRING to tree

Tags: xpath, xquery, sequence

I have a list of strings with information about how deep they are located in an XML tree. The strings at "the bottom," i.e. those elements that occur before an element with a lower depth, contain text.

`a_text,b_text,c_text,g1_text,b_text,c_text,g2_text,b_text,g1_text,g2_text,b_text,e_text`

I would like to reconstitute this as the XML tree below, in one operation.

```
<AA>
<a>text</a>
<b>text</b>
<c>text</c>
<g1_1>
    <g1>text</g1>
    <b>text</b>
    <c>text</c>
    <g2_2>
        <g2>text</g2>
        <b>text</b>
    </g2_2>
</g1_1>
<g1_1>
    <g1>text</g1>
    <b>text</b>
</g1_1>
<e>text</e></AA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why in your example the penultimate b_text is not in a g2 group, and I don't understand why the final e_text is outside any group. However, the following query:

```
declare function local:grouping($seq as element()*, $level as xs:integer) as element()* {
    for tumbling window $w in $seq
    start $s at $p when $p eq 1 or matches(name($s), "^g"||$level)
    return if (matches(name($s), "^g"||$level)) 
           then element {name($s)||"_"||$level} {local:grouping($w, $level+1)}
           else $w
};

let $seq := 
    let $in := "a_text,b_text,c_text,g1_text,b_text,c_text,g2_text,b_text,g1_text,g2_text,b_text,e_text"
    for $t in tokenize($in, ",")
    return element {substring-before($t, "_")} {substring-after($t, "_")}
return local:grouping($seq, 1)
```

produces the result

```
<a>text</a>
<b>text</b>
<c>text</c>
<g1_1>
   <g1>text</g1>
   <b>text</b>
   <c>text</c>
   <g2_2>
      <g2>text</g2>
      <b>text</b>
   </g2_2>
</g1_1>
<g1_1>
   <g1>text</g1>
   <g2_2>
      <g2>text</g2>
      <b>text</b>
      <e>text</e>
   </g2_2>
</g1_1>
```

which is the closest I can get to understanding your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to credit you for your posting!

Comment: I made a mistake when I copied the example.Result xml ends </AA><e>text</e> is outside of groups and b_text can be in other groups.